# How do you add a RouteValueDictionary to a T4MVC ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, t4mvc

There seems to be no extension method to include some arbitrary route values that normally I would expect to go into the querystring.

Old code:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink(Model.ParentMessage.Category.Text, "index", null, new { category = Model.ParentMessage.CategoryID }, new { })%>
```

I want to change it to this but it takes the category as an HTML attribute.

```
<%: Html.ActionLink(Model.ParentMessage.Category.Text, MVC.Feedback.Index(), new { category = Model.ParentMessage.CategoryID })%>
```

Just checking this isn't already possible before I write my own extension method as *surely* this was already accounted for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's there! :)  See the doc (http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC_doc).  Look for "Adding additional route parameters".

e.g. either:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink(Model.ParentMessage.Category.Text, MVC.Feedback.Index().AddRouteValue(category, Model.ParentMessage.CategoryID))%>
```

or

```
<%: Html.ActionLink(Model.ParentMessage.Category.Text, MVC.Feedback.Index().AddRouteValues(new { category = Model.ParentMessage.CategoryID }))%>
```

Comment: Non other than David Ebbo himself :)